# Showing that the product group of $G$ and $H$ satisfies the universal property for coproducts in the category of abelian groups $\mathbf{Ab}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-groups

I'm working on another problem of Aluffi's Algebra. Given the category $\mathbf{Ab}$ of abelian groups, the problem is to show that for any two groups $G$ and $H$ the product group $G\times H$ satisfies the universal property for coproducts in $\mathbf{Ab}$.

This amounts to showing that $G\times H$ is initial in the category $\mathbf{Ab}^{G,H}$. In other words we need to find a homomorphism $\sigma\in\text{Hom}(G\times H,K)$ and two suitable homomorphisms $\psi_G\in\text{Hom}(G,G\times H)$ and $\psi_H\in\text{Hom}(H,G\times H)$ such that for given $\varphi_G\in\text{Hom}(G,K)$ and $\varphi_H\in\text{Hom}(H,K)$ we have
\begin{equation}
\sigma\circ\psi_G=\varphi_G\\
\sigma\circ\psi_H=\varphi_H
\end{equation}
I think that defining 
\begin{equation}
\psi_G(g):=(g,e_H)\\
\psi_H(h):=(e_G,h)\\
\sigma(g,h):=\varphi_G(g)\varphi_H(h)
\end{equation}
(where $e_G,e_H$ are the identities of $G$ and $H$ and the last product is in $K$) gives the homomorphism we want (checking that $\sigma$ is actually a group homomorphism requires commutativity, so this won't work in $\mathbf{Grp}$), but my problem is proving uniqueness of $\sigma$. Any hints?

Comment: Maybe it is worth pointing out that $\psi_G$ and $\psi_H$ are a part of the coproduct structure of $G\times H$ - only once those are chosen, then any $\varphi_G$ and $\varphi_H$ induce a unique map $\sigma$.

Comment: (I say this because the second paragraph seems to suggest I might be able to pick $\psi_G$ and $\psi_H$ after I pick $\varphi_G$ and $\varphi_H$.)

Comment: @marco: Your statement of the universal property is wrong. Please be careful about the logic!

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Could you please correct me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conditions $\sigma\circ\psi_{G}=\varphi_{G}$ and $\sigma\circ\psi_{H}=\varphi_{H}$
are **determining** for $\sigma$. This because:

$\sigma\left(g,h\right)=\sigma\left(\left(g,e_{H}\right)\left(e_{G},h\right)\right)=\sigma\left(g,e_{H}\right)\sigma\left(e_{G},h\right)=\sigma\circ\psi_{G}\left(g\right)\sigma\circ\psi_{H}\left(h\right)=\varphi_{G}\left(g\right)\varphi_{H}\left(h\right)$

Comment: Thank you @drhab- I still don't see clearly how uniqueness of $\sigma$ follows from this.

Comment: Suppose that for some $\tau$ we also have $\tau\circ\psi_{G}=\varphi_{G}$
and $\tau\circ\psi_{H}=\varphi_{H}$. Then likewise we find that 

$\tau(g,h)=\tau((g,e_{H}),(e_{G},h))=\tau(g,e_{H})\tau(e_{G},h)=\tau\circ\psi_{G}(g)\tau\circ\psi_{H}(h)=\varphi_{G}(g)\varphi_{H}(h)=\sigma(g,h)$.
Showing that $\tau=\sigma$.

Comment: Maybe the point I'm missing here is that there is no other possible definition for $\psi_G$ and $\psi_H$? Are they as "canonical" as the canonical projections from the product $G\times H$ to the factors $G$ and $H$?

Comment: You mean the inclusions $G \to G \times H \leftarrow H$. not the projections. Also, you should recall the definition of a coproduct.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg No, I meant the projections- I wanted to draw an analogy between the inclusions and the projections: my doubt is, are the inclusions as canonical as the projections? (maybe it's just something that I have to get used to)

Comment: A coproduct must be looked at an *object together with inclusions*. In that context the uniqueness of $\sigma$ stands. Btw, what is your definition of canonical? Set $\mathbb R^2$ accompanied with e.g. the maps $(x,y)\mapsto -x$ and $(x,y)\mapsto 2y$ as projections can also be classified as a 'product'. In fact the existence and uniqueness of a map $h$ such that.. *makes* it a product.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifying comments. I am just beginning to study these themes by myself, so progress is quite slow.

Comment: $\Phi_G$ and $\Phi_H$ are not surgective, so it seems like there are many possible functions that could differ by where they map these unused parts of the domain, thus making $\sigma$ not unique.

Comment: I guess the requirement for $G \times H$ to be a group and for $\sigma$ to be a group homomorphism forces only one of these possible functions to be suitable.

Comment: @Kevin Your second comment is correct and actually enlightens why your first comment is not really relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the two morphisms
\begin{align}
i&\colon G\to G\times H, &&i(x)=(x,1)\\
j&\colon H\to G\times H, &&j(y)=(1,y)
\end{align}
(what you called $\psi_G$ and $\psi_H$).

If $\alpha\colon G\to K$ and $\beta\colon H\to K$ are morphisms of abelian groups, then you can define
$$
\sigma\colon G\times H\to K
$$
by
$$
\sigma(x,y)=\alpha(x)\beta(y)
$$
and, of course, $\sigma\circ i=\alpha$, $\sigma\circ j=\beta$.

Since $G\times H$ is generated by the images of $i$ and $j$, because $(x,y)=i(x)j(y)$, the morphism $\sigma$ is unique, for we know what its action must be on a set of generators.